# Java Shape Utilities

Tags: java, jfreechart, shapes

How to set such kind of points - small circles? I know we should set render and ShapeUtilies:

```
render.setSeriesShape(NumberOfSerie, ShapeUtilities.[something here]);
```

what should i write to get this circles? [Documentation is here.](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/util/ShapeUtilities.html)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ShapeUtilities class has some methods to create shapes that aren't provided by default in Java2D.  For circles though, you can just use:

```
Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(-3.0, -3.0, 6.0, 6.0);
```

The circle here is centered on (0, 0) - JFreeChart relies on that because it will translate the position of the shape to (x, y) when drawing the chart.

Comment: yes, `render.setSeriesShape(j, new Ellipse2D.Double(-2.0, -2.0, 4.0, 4.0));` is works, thank you!